# What would be the best way to let Box2D handle collision on different (simulated) heights?

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, box2d

I'm working on a 2D top-down game but we are also using a Z coordinate. This is to simulate the effect of 3D/height. Now the player can walk under a bridge and also over a bridge. The next thing I did was manage collision at these different heights. I got it working that the player collides with the bridge edge when he walks over it, but when he walks under it, he doesn't collide. But I'm not sure if I've done this correctly.

The way I'm currently doing it, is using different bits for different heights:

```
public static final short ENTITY_Z0_BIT = 1;
public static final short ENTITY_Z1_BIT = 2;
public static final short ENTITY_Z2_BIT = 4;
public static final short COLLISION_Z0_BIT = 8;
public static final short COLLISION_Z1_BIT = 16;
public static final short COLLISION_Z2_BIT = 32;
```

And then a collision body on Z 1 (or second floor) will have the following filter:

```
fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = COLLISION_Z1_BIT;
fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = ENTITY_Z1_BIT;
fixtureDef.filter.groupIndex = (short) 0;
```

This will mean the wall on the second floor will only collide with an entity on the second floor, because I also change the entity's filter depending on if their Z coordinate increases/decreases. This means I have to add more bits if I need a higher simulated Z-axis and it also doesn't allow for dynamic z-axis handling as I will need to do a big switch-case or if-statements for every Z-axis and then set the filter accordingly.

My second option was setting the groupIndex to be the same as the collision/entity's z-axis + 1. If a collision body and an entity body both have groupIndex 1, they will ALWAYS collide. However if the entity moves up on the z-axis, it's groupIndex will be set to 2 and thus it won't collide anymore. This also seemed like a nice and more dynamic idea. But then anything that needs to collide with a wall or entity, automatically also collides with all the other bodies that need the same groupIndex for the same reason. This doesn't allow for a lot of flexibility.

Which of these 2 options is best? And if there's another better way to handle this, do let me know!

Comment: It sounds like you thoroughly understand the trade-offs you're making with each option. Which one is more appropriate for the game you're making is something best decided by someone who is an expert in your game project, and the way your team prefers to work: you!

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks! I guess I was hoping that there was a common and "correct" way of handling this. Or that I missed something that would make my decision a lot easier or another way of achieving what I want.

Comment: In game development, there's very rarely a single universally-agreed "correct" way to do anything. Each game makes its own idiosyncratic choices and trade-offs.

Comment: There is also the option to set a custom function that decides what collides with what. Unfortunately I don't know Java so I can't make an answer. But you should look into the `SetContactFilter` function. ("Need more control?" section of www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering)